# format excel sheet using php

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to download a report using php from database. I am successful in getting the data but I am stuck at formatting the cells.  Can any one guide me how to format Excel?

I cannot use any 3rd party plugin like PHPExcel or Spread Sheet Writer.

I tried concatenating html code in php, but no use.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<?PHP




session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['desion'])){$data=$_SESSION['desion'];}else{$data="";};

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
unset($data[$i]['comid']);
}

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= DecisionMaker.xls");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");



 $flag = false;
 foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row

      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
  echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: formatting can be done using PHPExcel or any other library only, because that classes are mainly handling formatting part.

Comment: You might want to try exporting to csv [Creating downloadable CSV files using PHP](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/).

Comment: @PhilCooper - that's what Poster's code is doing, albeit using a bad homebrew CSV creating rather than using PHP's built-in function

Comment: @MarkBaker ok, just looked at the content-type and and file extension and wasn't sure which way it was going.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating an Excel spreadsheet, you're creating a CSV file, which is simply a file format that MS Excel is capable of importing. And CSV files have no formatting by their nature, they're simply raw data. If you want formatting, then you need to create a real native format Excel file (either the older BIFF format `.xls` file, or the newer OfficeOpenXML format `.xlsx` file).... to do this, you really want to use one of the many PHP libraries for creating native format Excel files, such as PHPExcel (whether you want to or not) otherwise you'll have to spend a lot of time writing your own.

And for reference, PHP has a built-in fputcsv() function that can be used to create csv files correctly, so you don't need to use that "homebrew" you're currently using